# How to use Non-Standard Custom Font with Stylesheets?

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

I have a `PyQt4` application that is being styled by an external `.qss` file by using the following code:

```
...
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
stylesheet = open('mystylesheet.qss').read()
app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
...
```

Normally, I would specify the type of font that I like in the `.qss` file to use like this:

```
QMainWindow
{
font-family:arial;
font-size:14px;
}
```

But, now I am wondering if it is possible for me to assign a custom font that I downloaded from internet (example, **DroidSansMono** (True Type Font) ) instead of windows standard font?

*NOTE: I am using Windows XP SP3 32 bits, with Python 2.7*

### UPDATE 1:

Based on Ekhumoro answer:

I can use the custom font downloaded by adding it to the font database before loading the `Stylesheet`:

```
QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Resources/Mf Wedding Bells.ttf")
```

After that, I can simply use the font name that I have just added in the stylesheet like this:

```
QLabel
{
font-family:Mf Wedding Bells;
font-size:16px;
}
```

And it works!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is just a guess, because I cannot test it myself, but you could try [loading the font](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont) before setting the stylesheet:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('path/to/font')
# or load the font data directly
# QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFontFromData(fontdata)
stylesheet = open('mystylesheet.qss').read()
app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```